# Use Eloquent to filter by pivot table in Laravel 5.3

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I am using Laravel's (5.3) Eloquent ORM and try to filter using a pivot table. I have three tables: `events`, `supervisors` and `event_has_supervisors`. Now I just want all events assigned to a certain supervisor.

In my Event Model I got this:

```
public function supervisors() {
    return $this->belongsToMany(Supervisor::class, 'event_has_supervisors')->withPivot('hours');
}
```

In my Controller I now need to query all events, given a few criteria:

```
$events = Event::with($relations);
// This works well: get all Events in one or more given cities
$events = $events->whereIn('events.place_id', $cities);
// This does not work
$events = $events->whereIn('events.supervisor_id', $supervisors);
```

Obviously, the last where-clause doesn't work, because there is no such attribute on my events table. But how can I query my pivot table in this case? I want any of the supervisors assigned to the event to be any of the supervisors in `$supervisors`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`whereHas`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence) as:

```
$events = $events->whereHas('supervisors', function($q) use($supervisors) {
   $q->whereIn('supervisor_id', $supervisors);
});
```

Comment: Worked perfectly, thank you. Only thing I had to amend was the 'supervisor_id' column, because I use it in both tables and got the 'ambiguous column name' error.